# Simulating dialogs and popup windows with Prism MVVM?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm, prism

I'm considering migrating a MVVM project to the Prism framework and would like to know if Prism will easily support "simulated" dialog windows and popups, each potentially with it's own regions.  By simulated, I mean a control on the main shell that has the appearance of a dialog or pop-up, without being an actual window.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in fact it works very well (your approach is exactly what we do).

Just one thing, Make sure that your register your region with the correct IRegionManager, we have had a few issues where it would be registered to the wrong IRegionManager.

if you need any examples / guidance then just give me a shout!

cheers.
ste.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's work well as simple silverlight.
So no worry about simulated dialog and Popups.
It is open same as Simple MVVM.

Also good idea to move into PRISM.

Ask me if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks, but for the user experience I'm going after I want to simulate modal dialogs over my main application window.